# Error while token management process in lambda (Java runtime) "Unable to load credentials from service endpoint: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException"

Tags: java, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Info about my use case -

- Lambda is in AWS account A
- S3 in AWS Account B

File upload event in S3 (Present in AWS account B) triggers lambda function (Present in AWS account A), lambda function take S3 event as input and must download file from S3.
Lambda is configured with IAM role which has a policy attached. Policy has access to S3 (Present in AWS account B).

In order for lambda to interact with S3, lambda server must have aws token set (which it does itself using IAM role) and then assume role to set token profile for interacting with S3 without getting access denied. And to do so I have written AWSTokenManager (class code shared below) in my lambda function which when executed throws this error -

```
Unable to load credentials from service endpoint: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException
    com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.handleError(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:183)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:162)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:82)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:164)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1166)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:762)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:724)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1271)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1247)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:454)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:54)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:116)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider$InstanceMetadataCredentialsEndpointProvider.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:122)
```

And here is AWSTokenManager class code - 
    package com.packagename;

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicSessionCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials;

public class AWSTokenManager {

public void awsTokenManager() {
    System.out.println("Inside awsTokenManager method");
    basicSessionCredentials();
}


BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials() {
    System.out.println("Call reached inside basicSessionCredentials method");

    AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance()).build();

    AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
            .withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::111:role/iamrolenamehere").withRoleSessionName("role_profilename");

    return gets3Credentials(stsClient, roleRequest);
}

public static BasicSessionCredentials gets3Credentials(AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient, AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest) {
    Credentials s3Credentials = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest).getCredentials();

    BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
            s3Credentials.getAccessKeyId(), s3Credentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
            s3Credentials.getSessionToken());

    return basicSessionCredentials;
 }
}
```

Also note that `no_proxy` and `NO_PROXY` environment variable in lambda configuration has `169.254.169.254`. Reason I did this is to avoid proxy issue while connecting to AWS service which according to my understanding runs on ip given above.

Comment: I was able to get pass above error by updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get pass above error by updating `awstokenManager` method to -

```
public void awsTokenManager() {
        System.out.println("Inside awsTokenManager method");
        STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(iAM_ROLE_ARN_TO_ASSUME, "us-east-1b")
                .withStsClient(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().build())
                .withRoleSessionDurationSeconds(900)
                .build();
        System.out.println("SessionCredentials awsaccesskeyid is - " + stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
        System.out.println("SessionCredentials awsaccesskeyid is - " + stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());
        System.out.println("SessionCredentials awsaccesskeyid is - " + stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getSessionToken());
        }
```